# how to temporarily use std::cout in place of std::ofstream

Tags: c++

if I want to create a logging class, say

```
class logging_class {
public:
    std::ofstream error;
    std::ofstream event;
    logging_class() {}
    logging_class(string err, string evt) {
        error.open(err);
        event.open(evt);
    }
    ~logging_class() {
        error.close();
        event.close();
    }
};
```

so that later I can easily create program log:

```
logging_class logger("Log_Error.txt","Log_Event.txt");
logger.error << "something wrong";
logger.event << "something interesting";
```

Now, at the early stage of development, I want to redirect all the output to screen (i.e. std::cout). I don't want to change the usage of `logger.error<<"something wrong";` to `std::cout<<"something wrong";`, because later I will need to change all instances of `std::cout` to either `logger.error` or `logger.event` (maybe thousands of them). Can I make some easy changes in the class logger to do this?

Update: Following Enlico's instruction, I can modify the `logging_class` as:

```
class logging_class {
public:
    //std::ofstream error;
    //std::ofstream event;
    std::ostream& error;
    std::ostream& event;
    logging_class():error(std::cout),event(std::cout) {}
    //logging_class(string err, string evt) {
    //    error.open(err);
    //    event.open(evt);
    //}
    //~logging_class() {
    //    error.close();
    //    event.close();
    //}
};
```

and after creating object with default constructor:
`logging_class logger;`
I can now redirect all the logging to screen display.

Comment: `ostream& error` and initialize it with the desired stream.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/NXfdSYLXv is a way of doing it using a pointer so that you can change between streams - that way you can have it set to cout until the program reads its config file to find out where the logging should go.  You could use an ostream reference but then you need to know where it is going when you construct the logger class.  Or, you could always just make a ostream and change the rdbuf so that it points to different places: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860267/what-can-go-wrong-if-cout-rdbuf-is-used-to-switch-buffer-and-never-set-it-back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of `std::cout` of what it actually is: an object. [It is just that:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)

> The global objects `std::cout` and `std::wcout` control output to […]

So when you say that you want to temporarily use `std::cout` in place of `std::ofstream` you're mixing apples (object `std::cout`) with oranges (class `std::ofstream`).

What you want to do, instead, is to use `std::cout` instead of *an object of* class `std::ofstream`.

But `std::cout` is not of class [`std::ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), so `error` can't hold it; it is of class [`std::ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream), which is a superclass of the former.

Therefore, as suggested in a comment, you can make `error`/`event` references to an object of that class, <s>`std::ofstream`</s>`std::ostream&`, and initialize them with `std::cout` or with `std::ofstream{"filename.txt"}` via an appropriate constructor of the `logging_class`.